# Fix closing tags with Java

Tags: java, regex

I have the following excerpt (in a String):

```
<Name/>Jhon<Name/><Number/>123B<Number/> <Cod Id="70" />ABCD9<Cod/>
```

I would like to correct the closing of the tags, to:

```
<Name>Jhon</Name><Number>123B</Number> <Cod Id="70" >ABCD9</Cod>
```

Any suggestions using java?

I tried like this:

```
Set<String> tagsOk = new HashSet<String>();
String tag = null;
String temp = null;
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<([^\\s>/]+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(xml);
while(m.find()) {
    tag = m.group(1);
    if(!tagsOk.contains(tag)) {
        temp = StringUtils.substringBetween(xml, "<"+tag+"/>", "<"+tag+"/>");
        xml = xml.replaceAll("<"+tag+"/>"+temp+"<"+tag+"/>", "<"+tag+">"+temp+"</"+tag+">");
    }
    tagsOk.add(tag);
}
```

UPDATE 1:

I forgot to mention, but they can be tags within tags

```
</tag Id="456" ><Name/>Jhon<Name/><Number/>123B<Number/> <Cod Id="70" />ABCD9<Cod/></tag >
```

Comment: Are you using any form of validator? I am thinking that you might be able to use the information on the exception message to fix the existing issue. Normally, something like a `MalformedXMLException` will contain the location of the error. HOWEVER, what you are trying to do is strongly discouraged. Instead, you should focus your error so that the XML string is generated correctly (against some sort of schema).

Comment: Your update may have invalidated the answer. That isn't kosher here.

Comment: What I reported above is just an example, I get RETURN from another system, which I don't have access to. It is a much larger xml, I did something brief to make it easier.

Comment: You should have accepted the answer (if it works), then asked a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Any suggestions using java?

How about the following.

```java
/*
 * import java.util.regex.Matcher;
 * import java.util.regex.Pattern;
 */
String str = "<Name/>Jhon<Name/><Number/>123B<Number/> <Cod Id=\"70\" />ABCD9<Cod/>";
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(str.length());
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(<.+?/>)([^<]+)?");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
while (matcher.find()) {
    String one = matcher.group(1);
    String two = matcher.group(2);
    if (two == null  ||  two.strip().length() == 0) {
        one = one.replace("<", "</");
        one = one.replace("/>", ">");
        two = "";
    }
    else {
        one = one.replace("/>", ">");                
    }
    result.append(one);
    result.append(two);
}
System.out.println(result);
```

`one` is the [XML] tag since, in your example string, each "start" tag has an identical "end" tag.

`two` is the [XML] tag "contents".

Running the above code prints the following:

```
<Name>Jhon</Name><Number>123B</Number><Cod Id="70" >ABCD9</Cod>
```

Comment: thanks!

I forgot to mention, but they can be tags within tags


</tag Id="456" ><Name/>Jhon<Name/><Number/>123B<Number/> <Cod Id="70" />ABCD9<Cod/></tag >

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to get away with a regular expression accompanied by a find-and-replace in a loop, such as this:

```
public static String correctTags(String str) {
    Pattern patt = Pattern.compile("<([A-Z]+)([^/]*)/>(.*?)<\\1/>", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

    boolean changed;
    do {
        changed = false;
        Matcher m = patt.matcher(str);
        String strNew = m.replaceAll("<$1$2>$3</$1>");
        if (!strNew.equals(str)) {
            changed = true;
            str = strNew;
        }
    } while (changed);

    return str;
}
```

The key here is the use of capturing groups (bits of the regex inside parentheses), plus the use of \1 that means 'an occurrence of whatever characters were captured as part of group 1'. Similarly, in the replacement, $1 means "whatever characters were captured as part of group 1". Then similarly, group 2 is any attribute content after the tag name, and group 3 is the tag contents. Of course, to deal robustly with all the possibilities of XML, the expression would need to be expanded considerably, and would probably reach a point where it wasn't practical to use regular expressions. But this quick-and-dirty solution may work for your specific case.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the suggestions, I managed to solve it as follows:

```
Map<String, String> mapTag = new HashMap<String, String>();
String tagTemp = null;
String startTag = null;
String endTag = null;
String contentTag = null;
String key = null;
int end = 0;
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(<.+?/>)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(xml);
while(m.find()) {
    tagTemp = m.group(1);
    end = tagTemp.indexOf(" ");
    if(end == -1) {
        end = tagTemp.indexOf("/");
    }
    key = tagTemp.substring(0, end).replace("<", "");
    if(mapTag.containsKey(key)) {
        startTag = mapTag.get(key);
        endTag = tagTemp;
        contentTag = StringUtils.substringBetween(xml, startTag, endTag); 
        xml = xml.replace(startTag+contentTag+endTag, startTag.replace("/>", ">")+contentTag+endTag.replace("/>", ">").replace("<", "</"));
    }else {
        mapTag.put(key, tagTemp);
    }
}
xml = xml.replaceAll(" >", ">");
```